# Deriving The Symmetry Formula of Selberg (Prime Number Theorem)

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, self-learning, analytic-number-theory, arithmetic-functions

It has been written (in the article ["A discussion of the fundamental ideas behind Selberg’s Elementary proof of the prime-number theorem” by Steve Balady](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/%7Emay/VIGRE/VIGRE2006/PAPERS/Balady.pdf), page 7) that,

[image]

On page 10, it is written -
[image]

But I can not see how $(6.2)$ is obtained using $(4.5)$ from the previous line $$\sum_{d \leq x}\mu(d) \sum_{d' \leq \frac x d  }\log^2(d')$$,

I tried by simplifying (brute force, multiplication) but didn't yield the result,

Can any one kindly show that plz?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, there is a typo in the statement (6.2): the first sum should be multiplied by $x$. We can see that this is merely a typo by looking at how they use (4.10) right under.

With that in mind, it suffices to prove that
$$
\frac12 \sum_{n\le x}\log^2 n = \frac12 x\log^2 x - x\log x + x+ O(\log^2 x)
$$
and apply it to the sum $\sum_{d'\le\frac xd}\log^2 d'$.

I assume for convenience that $x$ is an integer. Look at (4.5) and take a sum over the whole equation:
$$
\frac12 \sum_{n\le x}\log^2 n = \sum_{n\le x}\sum_{m\le n}\frac{\log m}{m} - xC'+ O\left(\sum_{n\le x}\frac{\log n}{n}\right)
\tag{1}
\label{1}
$$
The last term is $O(\log^2x)$ by (4.5). The first term is equal to
$$ \begin{split}
\sum_{m=1}^x\sum_{n=m}^x\frac{\log m}{m}
&= \sum_{m=1}^x(x-m+1)\frac{\log m}{m}\\
&= (x+1)\sum_{m=1}^x\frac{\log m}{m} - \sum_{m=1}^x\log m\\
&= \frac12(x+1)\log^2 x + (x+1)C' + O\left(\log x\right) - \sum_{m=1}^x\log m
\end{split}
\tag{2}
\label{2}
$$
Here we used (4.5) again. I claim that
$$
\sum_{m=1}^x\log m = x\log x - x + O(\log x)
\tag{3}
\label{3}
$$
Plug \eqref{2} and \eqref{3} into \eqref{1}, and you get the result.

To prove \eqref{3}, you can use the same strategy on (4.4) instead of (4.5) in the article. The proof is completely analogous.

Let me know if you need more details on something :)

EDIT

Explanation of \eqref{2}, line 1: First we swap the order of summation, $\sum_{n=1}^x\sum_{m=1}^n = \sum_{m=1}^x\sum_{n=m}^x$, giving the left hand side of \eqref{2}. The terms in the sum are constant with respect to $n$, and $x-m+1$ is the number of terms in the inner sum, so the inner sum works out to be
$$
\sum_{n=m}^x\frac{\log m}{m}
= \frac{\log m}{m}\sum_{n=m}^x 1
= \frac{\log m}{m} (x-m+1)
$$

Comment: The following line is not clear , plz explain elaborately:$ \sum_{m=1}^x\sum_{n=m}^x\frac{\log m}{m}
= \sum_{m=1}^x(x-m+1)\frac{\log m}{m}
$

Comment: @Andrew I made an edit. Does it help?

Comment: $\sum_{n=1}^x\sum_{m=1}^n = \sum_{m=1}^x\sum_{n=m}^x$ was the problem,
for example, let $n=x=2,$ and consider an arbitrary function $f$, then,


$\sum_{n=1}^{x=2}\sum_{m=1}^{n=2} f(m)= \underbrace{\sum_{m=1}^{x=1} f(m)+ (\sum_{m=1}^{x=2} f(m))}_{\text{Total} \;  x=2 \; \text{times, in other words,}\sum_{n=1}^{x=2}}= f(1)+  (f(1) + f(2))$, but, 


$\sum_{m=1}^{x=2}\sum_{n=m}^{x=2} f(n)=\sum_{n=1}^{x=2} f(n)+\sum_{n=2}^{x=2} f(n)$
$=f(1)+ f(2) + f(2)$, thus, it looks like,  $\sum_{n=1}^x\sum_{m=1}^n \neq \sum_{m=1}^x\sum_{n=m}^x$ , where am i making mistake?

Comment: Also, can you mention any book where this kind of sum ($\sum_{n=1}^x\sum_{m=1}^n = \sum_{m=1}^x\sum_{n=m}^x$) has been described, plz? What is the name of this kind of sum, or how it is called?

Comment: I think you are making more than one mistake. But most importantly, you can't set $n=x=2$, because only $x$ is a variable you can set. $n$ is a dummy variable, some would call it. So fx with $x=2$, we get: $\sum_{n=1}^2\sum_{m=1}^nf(m) = \sum_{m=1}^1f(m) + \sum_{m=1}^2f(m) = f(1) + (f(1) + f(2))$. And $\sum_{m=1}^2\sum_{n=m}^2f(m) = \sum_{n=1}^2f(1) + \sum_{n=2}^2f(2) = (f(1) + f(1)) + f(2)$.

Comment: We are really summing over all pairs of $(n,m)$ satisfying $1\le n\le x \wedge 1\le m\le n$. You can show or convince yourself that this is the same pairs as those that satisfy $1\le m\le x \wedge m\le n\le x$. I would draw the region of pairs on paper if I were you (they make a triangle). As for a reference, I don't know. But the method is the same as when you change the order of integration and need to work out the new limits.